# Python Reportlab VerticalBarChart - add chart title

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm using VerticalBarChart  from reportlab.graphics.charts.barcharts, and I can't find a documentation to simply add to a title to the chart's bottom. Please help!

```
chart = VerticalBarChart()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the user guide the axis title attribute is not implemented yet, so no there is no quick solution for this.

> **title**
>
> Not Implemented Yet. This needs to be like a label, but also
>   lets you set the text directly. It would have a default
>   location below the axis.
>
> *(From the user guide Table 11-5 - XCategoryAxis properties)*

The next best solution is probably to add a paragraph under the chart and use a `KeepTogether` to make sure they will always be on the same page. Like this:

```
combined_flowable = KeepTogether([chart_flowable, bottom_title_paragraph])
```